# Excluir registros em duplicidade no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou utilizando um comando que é executado a cada segundo em node.js. Ele tem a função de excluir qualquer registro em duplicidade para um determinado item, que é especificado como no exemplo por `AND t1.auction_id = 1335`.

```
DELETE FROM bid_account t1
WHERE t1.id < (Select max(t1.id) FROM bid_account t2 WHERE t1.bidding_price = t2.bidding_price) AND t1.auction_id = 1335;
```

Eu preciso que ele exclua um registro que tenha um valor igual na coluna `bidding_price`, e mantenha somente um. Porém é importante que ele faça essa pesquisa não em toda a tabela, mas sim para um determinado item como informei no início, pela coluna `auction_id`.

Eu tentei rodar o comando acima, mas ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 't1
WHERE t1.id < (Select max(t1.id) FROM bid_account t2 WHERE t1.bidding_price ' na linha 1
```

O que tem de errado nessa query?

Utilizo o banco de dados MYSQL, e a tabela `bid_account` possuí a coluna `id` como índice e primária.

Se eu utilizar o SELECT abaixo, ele retorna os valores em duplicidade normalmente.

```
SELECT bidding_price, count(*) FROM bid_account WHERE `auction_id` = 1335 GROUP BY bidding_price Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
DELETE ba
    FROM bid_account ba JOIN
         (SELECT ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price, MAX(ba2.id) as max_id
          FROM bid_account ba2
          WHERE ba2.auction_id = ?
          GROUP BY ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price
         ) ba2
         ON ba2.auction_id = ba.auction_id AND
            ba2.bidding_price = ba.bidding_price AND
            ba2.max_id > ba.id
WHERE ba.auction_id = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que o `MySQL` não permite apelidos na instrução `DELETE`, você tem que executar assim:

```
DELETE FROM bid_account
WHERE id < (
    Select max(t2.id) FROM bid_account t2
    WHERE bidding_price = t2.bidding_price
) AND auction_id = 1335;
```

No `sub-select` você pode apelidar normalmente.